# How to read all spans inside the different divs?

Tags: jquery

I have a html like below. I am assigning adding the error text to spans by id using a                    loop. that is fine for me.

my html looks like below, each div contains a span with specific id's.

```
<div class="span3">  
   <span id="errorDepartmentName"></span> <-- clear this span
</div>
<div class="span3">
   <span id="errorDepartmentAbbreviation"></span> <-- clear this span
</div>
<div class="span3">
   <span id="errorPhoneNumber"></span> <-- clear this span
</div>
```

Is there any way to clear the data of all spans with our iterating each span element, all span id's are starting with error".

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: your question and code is totally unclear, give it another shot and i would be glad to help, this .html function seems to be what your looking for.

Comment: Adding the javascript code would also be helpful.

Comment: `$('.span3 [id^="error"]').empty();`

Comment: You should do some more research before asking something like this

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector like all child spans([child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)) of div element([element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)) with an id starting with `error`([attribute starting with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)) then use .html() to empty the content.

```
$('div > span[id^="error"]').html('')
```

If you want to be specific about the div with class span3 then use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) too like

```
$('div.span3 > span[id^="error"]').html('')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want to remove all the  of .span3... In that case, I think you should use something like this:

```
$('.span3').find('span').remove();
```